# Eliminar un array dentro de un Array Multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando en un sistema Point of Sale y necesito crear un reporte de los artículos vendidos, pero algunos articulos no tienen asignado nada en el campo 'item_variation_id' como puedo eliminar los arrays que tengan este campo vacío y conservar unicamente los que si contengan asignado algo en ese campo?

Este es una parte del array multidimensional resultado de mi consulta:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_variation_id] => 477 [item_id] => 200 [name] => Blusa de Crochet. Blusa SY630 [item_number] => [product_id] => Blusa 630 [quantity] => -10.0000000000 )
        [1] => Array ( [item_variation_id] => 479 [item_id] => 200  [name] => Blusa de Crochet. Blusa SY630 [item_number] => [product_id] => Blusa 630 [quantity] => -10.0000000000 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [item_variation_id] => [item_id] => 201 [name] => Botín BRECKELLES Ali-21 Talla: 22.5 Color: Negro/Dorado E-799 [item_number] => ALI21225799 [product_id] => 88542 [quantity] => 12.0000000000 )
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: iguala los elementos que quieras eliminar a `null` o crea una funcion para operarlo con `for`

Comment: Como puedo igualarlos a null?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo guardar los resultados de un array en otro array en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/435773/como-puedo-guardar-los-resultados-de-un-array-en-otro-array-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

Hay una [función especial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) para filtrar elementos de un arreglo:

```
var_dump( array_filter( $arrayMultidimensionalResultadoDeTuConsulta
                      , function($v,$k){ return isset($v['item_variation_id']); } 
                      , ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
                      ) 
        );
```

El primer argumento es tu arreglo, el segundo es la función de filtrado ya sea el nombre o una retrollamada. Con el tercero se determina si evalúas el elemento usando la clave, el valor o ambos.

No obstante, si la consulta es a una base de datos, tal vez sea mas simple agregar al SQL algo como: `WHERE item_variation_id is not null`.