# ¿Como puedo guardar los resultados de un array en otro array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tengo este array donde elimino los elementos con el campo 'item_variation_id' vacio con unset, esto me da como resultado un array con los indices desordenados, ¿como puedo guardar el resultado final en otro array para poder reindexarlo sin utilizar array_values?

```
$report_data = array (
               array ('item_variation_id' => "100" ,'item_id' => "100" ,'name' => " Blusa 1" ),
               array ('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 2" ),
               array ('item_variation_id' => "200" ,'item_id' => "200" , 'name' => " Blusa 3" ),
               array ('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 4" ),
               array ('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 5" ),
               array ('item_variation_id' => "300" ,'item_id' => "300" , 'name' => "Blusa 6" ));
```

Comment: Ayudaría un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado, puedes intentar con el siguiente código.

```
$report_data = array(
               array('item_variation_id' => "100" ,'item_id' => "100" ,'name' => " Blusa 1" ),
               array('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 2" ),
               array('item_variation_id' => "200" ,'item_id' => "200" , 'name' => " Blusa 3" ),
               array('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 4" ),
               array('item_variation_id' => " " ,'item_id' => "NADA" , 'name' => " Blusa 5" ),
               array('item_variation_id' => "300" ,'item_id' => "300" , 'name' => "Blusa 6" )
);

$aux_arr = array();

foreach($report_data as $key => $report)
{
    if(!empty(trim($report["item_variation_id"])))
    {
        $aux_arr[] = $report;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($aux_arr);
```

1. Debes crear un arreglo auxiliar en el cual almacenarás tus nuevos registros.
2. Debes recorrer el arreglo original con un ciclo en donde guardarás los registros que no tienen el 'item_variation_id' vacio.
3. Ya tienes tu nuevo arreglo con los indices ordenados